# Html/css: different "Download linked file..." than actual link

Tags: html, download

I'm quite new to the whole html language (started building my own website very recently).

Let me describe what my problem is:

I've got a kind of file tree looking menu setup that allows users to browse trough my website. Each item in it is a link to a html page that holds a version of the file that is highlighted with [syntaxhighlighter](http://code.google.com/p/syntaxhighlighter/):

```
<a href="files/hl_file.html" target="content_page">file.cpp</a>
```

Yet I would the user to be able to right click this link and use the "Save as..." menu to save the file itself. The way I set up things now doesn't allow for this since right-click-saving will just save the highlighting html file `hl_file.html` in stead of `file.cpp`.

In the above code `"content_page"` is an `iframe` that actually holds the whole web page.

Is there a way to build in some sort of extra into the href that handles right click downloading?

Comment: By default, no, you would need to use a lot of Javascript to handle the right clicks and show the options available.

Comment: yet it would be possible? There aren't that much different options IMO: left-click -> open html in `content_page` target, right-click ->  download the file `file.cpp`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put all your links to your code in a special class (eg. `.syntax`). Then you can alter your elements' behaviour with the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>basic demo</title>
<script>
window.addEventListener('load',function(){
    // run this function when the website is loaded completly
    // use DOMContentLoaded if you prefer to load it earlier.
    for(var i=0, p; p = document.querySelectorAll('a.syntax')[i];++i){
            // this will run through all anchor tags tagged with the class 'syntax'
        p.oldhref = p.href; // save old href
        p.addEventListener('mousedown',function(e){
                    // Capture mouse events
            if(e.button === 2) // Check for right click
                this.href = this.firstChild.data; // Right click
                // Please ensure that your a tag contents the correct link.
                // If not, alter it to 'src/' + this.firstChild.data
                // or whatever your src directory is.
            else
                this.href = this.oldhref; // left click, use original href
        },false);
    }
},false);
</script>
<body>
<a href="http://google.de" class="syntax">http://stackoverflow.com</a>
</body>
</html>
```

This won't change the behaviour of your browser, since all it does is changing the URL. See http://jsfiddle.net/wHB3m/1/

Comment: Oh I see it's specified in the link name. Works for me!

Comment: @romeovs: You're welcome. Yes, your file that needs to be downloaded is specified in `this.firstChild.data`, which is `<a href="...">this_URL</a>`. You can alter it as seen in the code. Have a look at http://www.w3schools.com/dom/dom_nodetype.asp

Answer (score 3):

There's no special href for directly downloading, but you can try replacing the right click menu with a custom menu, which has a link to the download you want to expose:

Demo: http://labs.abeautifulsite.net/archived/jquery-contextMenu/demo/

via: http://www.abeautifulsite.net/blog/2008/09/jquery-context-menu-plugin/

Set your HTML to:
`<a href="..." data-downloadhref="...">File</a>`

Then use in your "download" callback:
`document.location = $(el).data('downloadhref')`

**Edit**: This uses jQuery, so you'd need to use and be familiar with that to make it work. You could probably find a similar, jQuery-less script. Just google around for `Javascript Context Menu`.

Comment: +1 This is quite cool, yet I think it's too obtrusive. I there a way that uses the users look and feel (eg. looks like mac right click menu on a mac and like windows right click menu on windows)?